# IIS6, MVC, Handler Mappings, and CKFinder

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-6, ckfinder

Strange thing happening in IIS6 that does not happen in IIS7 and I need some assistance. For our redirects to work, we had to add handler mappings for .html, .htm, and .php files to point to: C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll

However, when trying to access CKFinder for browsing and uploading images within the CKEditor, it won't browse to the CKFinder.html page.

Does anyone know why this is happening in IIS6 and how I can preserve the redirects from the old .html pages and still open CKFinder?

Answer (score 0):

Someone is recommending changing the CKFinder.html file to .aspx and adjusting the JavaScript. I think this is my only way to go!